# Maven + Cobertura : Unable to locate [Your Class]. Have you specified the source directory?

Tags: java, maven, cobertura

I have "MyMath" class with 2 simple methods: "multi" and "add".
And test class which will only test multi method.

```
public class MainTest {

    @Test
    public void testMultiply() {

       MyMath tester = new MyMath();

       // check if multiply(10,5) returns 50
       assertEquals("10 x 5 must be 50", 50, tester.multi(10, 5));
     } 
}
```

My project structure is:

```
JenkinsTest/
 src/
  main/Main.java
  math/MyMath.java
  test/MathTest.java
```

And pom.xml at root of project.
I am trying to generate coverage report using cobertura-maven-plugin.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <formats>
           <format>html</format>
           <format>xml</format>
          </formats>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>  

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And run maven from command line `maven cobertura:cobertura`

It says 1 Test is run, Cobertura Report generation was successful, Build Success messages. But when I go check target/site/cobertura/index.html, it says "MyMath" class has 100% line coverage (Even though "add" method is not executed). When I click on "MyMath" link, it says "Unable to locate math/MyMath.java. Have you specified the source directory?". I am newbie to Maven and cobertura. Can somebody please kindly guide me to show the coverage result correctly and "Unable to locate" problem. Thank you.

PS: I changed the project structure to Maven Standard Directory Layout as @drembert advice and it works as excepted. But when I clicked the class name, the error: "Unable to locate **main/java/MyMath.java**. Have you specified the source directory?" is still there.

Comment: One thing I notice in your folder structure is that you are not following the standard Maven project structure ([Introduction to Maven Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)). For example MyMath.java should be in the src/main/java folder, preferably with the extra folders after this path to represent the package name.

Comment: Thank you very much @drembert . Now coverage show correct result. The error message is changed to "Unable to locate main/java/MyMath.java. Have you specified the source directory?".

Comment: Do you have maven-source-plugin in your POM file?

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan No I don't have one. I googled it and found that it generates jar archive of the source files. Do I need to add it sir?

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan I added <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId><version>2.2.1</version> to POM and run maven again. Download is completed. Build success. Coverage result correct. But still can't locate the file.

Comment: Have you defined source directory in your pom.xml somewhere?

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan No I didn't sir. I changed my project structure to Maven standard so I think it will use the default source directory (src/main/java). If I have to define, which directory do I have to define in my POM? Thank you very much for your time and patience.